# Substituir dados em texto

Tags: r

Estou trabalhando com um texto retirado do projeto Gutemberg. Trata-se de um livro. Preciso marcar o início de cada capítulo de forma regular. No formato atual, eles se encontram identificados apenas com números romanos maiúsculos. Por Exemplo:

> I Introdução
>
> II Trabalho

Eu precisava que ele se transformasse em:

> Capítulo 2 - Trabalho
>
> Capítulo 1 - Introdução

No total há 160 capítulos

Montei uma lista com números romanos de 1 a 160 a ser substituída no texto por outra lista, onde se leria Capítulo 1...Capítulo n. Mas não consegui uma função no R que me ajudasse a fazer tal substituição

Alguma dica de como proceder?

grato

Comment: Qual é o livro? Nem todos os livros do projeto Gutenberg têm os capítulos numerados com números romanos.

Comment: Esse tem, por isso fiz a lista. É o Dom Casmurro. Quero substituir a expressão regular para poder pesquisar no texto Obrigado @RuiBarradas!

Comment: vc consegue editar a pergunta com um exemplo reproduzível? Para mim, a mesma não ficou clara.

Comment: Seria ótimo se você editasse a pergunta  para torná-la clara. De qualquer forma, há funções no R, como a `roman2int` do pacote `gtools` que convertem números romanos para inteiros.

Comment: Olá já fiz a edição! Obrigado!